How to solve "Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly"
there!
I'm just trying to run Apach with XAMPP, but I get this error:
16:48:24  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
16:48:24  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
16:48:24  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
16:48:24  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
16:48:24  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
16:48:24  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
16:48:24  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums

Apach (error.log)
[Fri Sep 27 16:48:21.524906 2024] [ssl:warn] [pid 1188:tid 552] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Sep 27 16:48:21.604906 2024] [core:warn] [pid 1188:tid 552] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Fri Sep 27 16:48:21.606906 2024] [ssl:warn] [pid 1188:tid 552] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

And I can't figure out how to restore the certificate.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

What do you mean by "restore the certificate"? The certificate used by the http server is present, but it is not valid for the configured host name. You should compare that name with those the certificate is valid for. Nothing we can help with.
